# display previously fetched json data while fetching new data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to find an easy way to load previously downloaded data while fetching the new data. I don't want to use CoreData since I think it's a bit "much" for my use case. what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

1. download some json
2. save the json to disk
3. display the data
   user exits app and comes back
4. load the previously downloaded json
5. display the cached data
6. see 1.

Anyone got any pointers? How should i persist the data? I'm using SwiftyJson to handle my json needs.

Comment: how big is your data load that CoreData seems much? If it's small enough, you could try `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: It's a couple of 100k maximum, but don't you think using NSUserDefaults is a bit kludgy? @BHendricks

Comment: Ok, yea, `NSUserDefaults` shouldn't be used for this amount of data, why is CoreData "too much" for this much data?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Its maximum 10KBytes. @BHendricks

Comment: Ok, well...if you use `NSUserDefaults` you just need to store your result as a single key, assuming you have parsed the JSON into a Dictionary. This is, like you said, kludgy for any substantial amount of data.